# ddply timing and performance issue

Tags: r, performance, plyr

I could use some help dissecting the root of a timing issue with ddply. The ddply function is taking upwards of 10 minutes to run on a small data set (~4MB data frame).

I'm trying to run ddply in the following manner:

```
new_df<- ddply(old_df, .(TIC), mutate, mean_price_3yr=rollmean(price, k=3, align= "right",na.pad=T))
```

old_df is of the form:

```
   fyear TIC ebitda price
1   2000 AIR 64.367 14.00
2   2001 AIR 27.207 11.44
3   2002 AIR 30.745  4.50
4   2003 AIR 47.491  9.58
...
   fyear   TIC  ebitda price
21  2005  ADCT 159.000 17.450
22  2006  ADCT 140.400 14.310
23  2007  ADCT 167.900 18.700
24  2008  ADCT 173.300  6.340
25  2009  ADCT  84.700  8.340
26  2010  ADCT 121.400 12.670
27  2000 ALO.2 190.533 43.875
28  2001 ALO.2 163.601 26.450
29  2002 ALO.2 187.264 11.910
30  2003 ALO.2 155.228 20.100
31  2004 ALO.2 153.829 16.950
...
```

The intent of my ddply is to calculate the rolling mean of price the last 3 periods grouped by TIC. I ensured that there were at least 3 observations of a TIC before running the code. There are ~10,000 unique TIC out of 80,000 total rows.

With the help of another article, I was able to reuse the ave function to accomplish my task:

```
old_df$last3<-ave(old_df$price, old_df$TIC, FUN=function(x) rollmean(x, k=3, align= "right",na.pad=T))
```

Running this code takes about 1 second and accomplished the task satisfactorily.

I am running a Macbook Pro, 16GB RAM, 2.8GHz Intel Core i7. If anyone could help me diagnose the issue it would be greatly appreciated!

Update1: Here is a comparison of the run times in the actual application. I didn't include ddply results because I don't want to wait that long :P

```
> system.time(test<-epdata %>% group_by(LPERMNO) %>% mutate(mean_price_3yr = roll_mean(ebitda, n=3, align="right", fill=NA)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.570   0.007   0.577 

> system.time(epdata_2$delta_earnings<-ave(epdata_2$ebitda, epdata_2$LPERMNO, FUN=function(x) Delt(x, k=1, type = "arithmetic")))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.583   0.007   2.600
```

Comment: If you want to increase the speed, perhaps `dplyr` (an advanced package from the same authors) would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make it more efficient by using `roll_mean` from `library(RcppRoll)` along with `dplyr`

```
library(RcppRoll)
library(dplyr)
old_df %>% 
    group_by(TIC) %>%
    mutate(mean_price_3yr = roll_mean(price, n=3,
                  align="right", fill=NA))
```

#### data

```
old_df <- structure(list(fyear = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
   2003L, 2005L, 2006L, 
 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
 2004L), TIC = c("AIR", "AIR", "AIR", "AIR", "ADCT", 
"ADCT", "ADCT", 
"ADCT", "ADCT", "ADCT", "ALO.2", "ALO.2", "ALO.2", 
"ALO.2", "ALO.2"
), ebitda = c(64.367, 27.207, 30.745, 47.491, 159, 140.4,
167.9, 173.3, 84.7, 121.4, 190.533, 163.601, 187.264, 
155.228, 153.829), price = c(14, 11.44, 4.5, 9.58, 17.45, 
14.31, 18.7, 6.34, 8.34, 12.67, 43.875, 26.45, 11.91,
20.1, 16.95)), .Names = c("fyear", "TIC", "ebitda", 
"price"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Comment: thanks akrun. perfect example. works flawlessly and incredibly fast. I sincerely appreciate your help. any idea why ddply would take so long or what i might have been doing wrong?

Comment: @GeorgeBonebright  The `ddply` is a bit old package.  I guess one of the reasons they developed `dplyr` would be to make it more efficient.

Comment: makes sense. thanks again for your help. I updated the original question with my run time summaries fysa.

Comment: @GeorgeBonebright  Glad to help you and thanks for the update